# How to say this proverb?

Tags: proverb-requests

In Italian there's a religious proverb:

> Chi è senza peccato scagli la prima pietra

Is it correct to translate it to the following:

> Who isn't without sin the first stone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not here to translate.

Comment: It's a biblical quotation, so you can consult the Bible translation of your choice to find what you feel is most appropriate for your use.

Answer (score 3):

This is a biblical quotation, from the words of Jesus recorded in John 8:7. The King James Version of the second half of that verse says, 'He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her.' So it's not really any different in English.

Also, have you checked out [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) on Stack Exchange?

Comment: No, What is it?

Comment: @Mattew It's another Q&A site they run, which you might find more relevant if you are an Italian-speaker interested in learning English.

Answer (score 2):

***[Let him who is without sin cast the first stone](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_him_who_is_without_sin_cast_the_first_stone):***

> - An allusion to an utterance of Jesus’ in John 8:7, viz. “He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her.”
>
>   - Only those who are faultless have the right to pass judgment upon others (implying that no one is faultless and that, therefore, no one has such a right to pass judgment).

(Wiktionary)

Comment: It is usually rendered idiomatically, (at least in Britain) as *Let he that be without sin cast the first stone*.